# How do I call the PerformClick() function in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, button

I have three different buttons but now I want to call each even at the same time using one `button`.

I am unable to find the `button.PerformClick()` option, instead I have `button.PerformLayout()`.

This is what I have:

```
private void ButtonTagStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Something
}

private void ButtonLoadxHTMLTags_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Something
}

private void btnStrt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

I want:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonTagStart.PerformClick();
    ButtonLoadxHTMLTags.PerformClick();
    btnStrt.PerformClick();
}
```

What shall I do?

Comment: is that a click event? why don't you do that on button2_click?

Comment: Winforms? Normally it should be possible, all buttons should have [PerformClick()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.performclick). Maybe those are not buttons? [PeformLayout()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.performlayout) is a method for `Control`. Or it could be some other problem which is hard to see without [mcve].

Comment: You are supposed to tag your question with the UI framework you are using.  Probably not [winforms] then.  It is not the right way to do it anyway, move the code in those Click event handlers into another private method.  And call those methods directly, you don't need PerformClick anymore.

Comment: Sorry! Yes, I am using WinForms and .NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

you can create a method for each button

```
private void Something1(){}
private void Something2(){}
private void Something3(){}
private void ButtonTagStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Something1();
}

private void ButtonLoadxHTMLTags_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Something2();
}

private void btnStrt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Something3();
}
```

in the last button invoke them all:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Something1();
  Something2();
  Something3();
}
```